# ExtJs Controller calls view with data

Tags: ajax, extjs, model-view-controller, sencha-touch

I'm trying to call a view from an AJAX call, written in the controller, sending also data stored in a model.

This is the call:

```
var dummyAttivita = Ext.create('appTrial.model.Attivita', {
   id: 1,
   nomeAttivita :  'il Chiosco',
   codiceAttivita: 'ago123'
});
.
.
.

doLogin: function() {
    // called whenever the Login button is tapped
    var codAttivita = Ext.getCmp('codAttivita').getValue();
    if( codAttivita != null || codAttivita !== undefined ) {
        if (codAttivita.length > 0) {
            if (codAttivita === dummyAttivita.get('codiceAttivita')) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('', 'entro', Ext.emptyFn);
                var attivitaAssociata = Ext.encode(dummyAttivita.getFields);
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : 'app/view/Postazione.js/',
                    method:'POST',
                    params,: {attivitaAssociata : dummyAttivita.getFields}
                    scope : this,

                    success : function(response, opts){
                      //What should I put here???
                    },
                    //method to call when the request is a failure
                    failure : function(response, opts){
                        Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Nothing', Ext.emptyFn);
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Il codice inserito non è associato ad alcuna attivita', Ext.emptyFn);
            }
        } else {
            Ext.Msg.alert('', 'Inserisci il codice di una attivita', Ext.emptyFn);
        }
    }
},
```

What I'm not understanding is how to load the new view specified in the url parameter, sending also data stored on params.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Ago

Comment: what is that view(form panel,tab panel or container),what it contains?

Comment: It is a simple container just with html text for the moment; do I have to update the post with calling and called views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
success : function(response){
    var returnJson = JSON.parse(response.responseText);

    // either work with a store or save the data somewhere else
    Ext.getStore('MyStore').add(returnJson);
    // or you use your model (if data.is the base path inside the Json
    dummyAttivita.set(returnJson.data);

    // Here you add a route (should be inside the view controller
    MyApp.app.redirectTo('newView');

    // alternative to Ext.getStore() is to use a tpl for the view
    newView.setData(returnJson);
},
```

Comment: The line:"var returnJson = JSON.parse(response.responseText); gives me the error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token E

Comment: how does your response look like. Can you write it into your post?

Comment: It contains the model defined into the url attribute of the ajax call:
"response.responseText: "Ext.define('appTrial.model.Attivita'.."

Comment: please. Can you please a demo callback, so that I can see the result. It could be that the returning responseText is not valid JSON. But need to see that.

Comment: Sorry Proto, thanks for you help, but for the moment I overcome the problem just using a Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem in order to load the new mask. I'll face with it soon and I'll come back with the JSON. Very appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you can write your success function like below.

```
  success : function(response, opts){
       Ext.getCmp('container_id').setHtml(Ext.decode(response.responseText));
  },
```

Comment: Not working, but probably I didn't explain it correctly: I have a view, Login.js, with a container called loginContainer. The Ajax call above is inside the controller called by the Login.js. Now, onSuccess of the AJAX call, I would call the Postazione.js, defined on the url of the ajax call, made by postazioneContainer, on the place of the Login view.